# Error getting developer license

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I am working in C# & WPF  and now I want to get start with split app or grid app or a universal windows 8.1 app.  The problem is that I need a developer license to get start with programming.  When I agreed to install developer license on my Windows 8.1 I got the error below. Is there anyway to fix it?
I Googled for it a lot and haven't found an answer.

[image: Error Dialog]

Comment: Have you verified your not using a proxy or vpn that is blocking the communication?

Comment: @Ramhound no but im from syria is there any chance to be blocked from microsoft ?

Comment: It's entirely possible that your ISP is blocking the connection.  Have you verified if you use a VPN or Proxy you can connect?

Answer (score 0):

Run Command Prompt as administrator. 
Type netsh winhttp reset proxy at the command prompt, and press Enter. Try to get licence again.
It worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200158/unable-to-get-developer-license-for-windows-8